# How to properly write this usort function

Tags: php

I have an array of rows from a database I need to sort by two parameters. I have tried to use the `usort()` function to accomplish this, but I'm running into some trouble.

Here is my code:

```
if ($sort == 'rating-desc') usort($records, array('browse_model', 'cmp'));
private function cmp($a, $b) {
    $ratingCmp = strcmp($b['rating'], $a['rating']);
    if ($ratingCmp == 0) {
        return strcmp($b['title'], $a['title']);
    } else {
        return $ratingCmp;
    }
}
```

Here is the `print_r()` result of the array before `usort()`:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [isbn] => 1847199488
        [title] => CodeIgniter 1.7
        [rating] => 3.5
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [isbn] => 059615593X
        [title] => CSS Cookbook, 3rd Edition (Animal Guide)
        [rating] => 3.5
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [isbn] => 0321637984
        [title] => Essential Facebook Development: Build Successful Applications for the Facebook Platform
        [rating] => 3.5
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [isbn] => 0980576857
        [title] => jQuery: Novice to Ninja
        [rating] => 4.5
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [isbn] => 0596157134
        [title] => Learning PHP, MySQL, and JavaScript: A Step-By-Step Guide to Creating Dynamic Websites (Animal Guide)
        [rating] => 4.5
    )

)
```

And here is the the result after the `usort()` (sorted by rating, but not by title):

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [isbn] => 0980576857
        [title] => jQuery: Novice to Ninja
        [rating] => 4.5
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [isbn] => 0596157134
        [title] => Learning PHP, MySQL, and JavaScript: A Step-By-Step Guide to Creating Dynamic Websites (Animal Guide)
        [rating] => 4.5
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [isbn] => 0321637984
        [title] => Essential Facebook Development: Build Successful Applications for the Facebook Platform
        [rating] => 3.5
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [isbn] => 1847199488
        [title] => CodeIgniter 1.7
        [rating] => 3.5
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [isbn] => 059615593X
        [title] => CSS Cookbook, 3rd Edition (Animal Guide)
        [rating] => 3.5
    )

)
```

So it puts them in order by rating, but not by title. How can I modify this so it sorts by rating, then by title?

For what it's worth, I've also tried this:

```
if ($sort == 'rating-desc') {
        foreach ($records as $key => $row) {
            $rating[$key] = $row['rating'];
            $title[$key] = $row['title'];
        }
        array_multisort($title, SORT_DESC, $rating, SORT_ASC, $records);
    }
```

But that result isn't correct either. It shows the same result as the usort I tried above.

What am I missing?

Thanks much,
Marcus

EDIT: Following some of the suggestions below, here are several things I've tried. None of them solve my problem. They all return the ratings sorted properly, but the title is descending.

```
private function cmp($a, $b) {
    if ($a['rating'] == $b['rating']) {
        return strcasecmp($b['title'], $a['title']);
    }
    return $b['rating'] - $a['rating'];
}

private function cmp($a, $b) {
    if ($a['rating'] == $b['rating']) 
        return strcasecmp($a['title'], $b['title']);
    return $b['rating'] - $a['rating'];
}

    if ($sort == 'rating-desc') {
        foreach ($records as $key => $row) {
            $rating[$key] = $row['rating'];
            $title[$key] = $row['title'];
        }
        array_multisort($rating, SORT_DESC, $title, SORT_ASC, $records);
    }

    if ($sort == 'rating-desc') {
        foreach ($records as $key => $row) {
            $rating[$key] = $row['rating'];
            $title[$key] = $row['title'];
        }
        array_multisort($rating, SORT_DESC, $title, SORT_DESC, $records);
    }
```

Here is my entire code example - the entire model...

```
class Browse_model extends Model {

    function Browse_model() {
        parent::Model();
    }

    function get_form_tags() {
        $sql = 'select t.id, t.tag, coalesce(btc.count, 0) as count from tags as t left outer join (select tag_id, count(*) as count from books_tags group by tag_id) as btc on t.id = btc.tag_id order by count desc, tag asc';
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        $tags = $query->result();
        return $tags;
    }

    function get_book_info($tags, $andor, $read, $sort) {

        /*
         * SELECT b.isbn, b.title, b.publisher, b.date, b.thumb, b.filename, b.pages, t.tag
         * FROM books AS b
         * INNER JOIN books_tags AS bt ON b.isbn = bt.book_id
         * INNER JOIN tags AS t ON bt.tag_id = t.id
         * ORDER BY b.title, t.tag
         */

        switch ($sort) {
            case 'alpha-desc':
                $order = 'b.title DESC, t.tag';
                break;
            case 'date-desc':
                $order = 'b.date DESC, b.title, t.tag';
                break;
            case 'date-asc':
                $order = 'b.date, b.title, t.tag';
                break;
            default:
                $order = 'b.title, t.tag';
                break;
        }

        $this->db->select('b.isbn, b.title, b.publisher, b.date, b.thumb, b.filename, b.pages, t.tag');
        $this->db->from('books AS b');
        $this->db->join('books_tags AS bt', 'b.isbn = bt.book_id', 'inner');
        $this->db->join('tags AS t', 'bt.tag_id = t.id', 'inner');
        $this->db->order_by($order);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $result = $query->result();

        $counter = '';
        $records = $meta = $tags = array();
        $count = count($result);
        $i = 1;

        foreach ($result as $book) {
            // If this is not the last row
            if ($i < $count) {
                // If this is the first appearance of this book
                if ($counter != $book->isbn) {
                    // If the meta array already exists
                    if ($meta) {
                        // Add the combined tag string to the meta array
                        $meta['tags'] = implode(', ', $tags);
                        // Add the meta array
                        $records[] = $meta;
                        // Empty the tags array
                        $tags = array();
                    }
                    // Reset the counter
                    $counter = $book->isbn;
                    // Grab the book from Amazon
                    $amazon = $this->amazon->get_amazon_item($book->isbn);
                    // Collect the book information
                    $meta = array(
                        'isbn' => $book->isbn,
                        'title' => strip_slashes($book->title),
                        'publisher' => strip_slashes($book->publisher),
                        'date' => date('F j, Y', strtotime($book->date)),
                        'thumb' => $book->thumb,
                        'file' => $book->filename,
                        'pages' => $book->pages,
                        'rating' => $amazon->Items->Item->CustomerReviews->AverageRating,
                        'raters' => $amazon->Items->Item->CustomerReviews->TotalReviews
                    );
                    // Add the tag to the tags array
                    $tags[] = $book->tag;
                } else {
                    // All we need is the tag
                    $tags[] = $book->tag;
                }
            // If this is the last row
            } else {
                // If this is the first appearance of this book
                if ($counter != $book->isbn) {
                    // Grab the book from Amazon
                    $amazon = $this->amazon->get_amazon_item($book->isbn);
                    // Collect the book information
                    $meta = array(
                        'isbn' => $book->isbn,
                        'title' => strip_slashes($book->title),
                        'publisher' => strip_slashes($book->publisher),
                        'date' => date('F j, Y', strtotime($book->date)),
                        'thumb' => $book->thumb,
                        'file' => $book->filename,
                        'pages' => $book->pages,
                        'rating' => $amazon->Items->Item->CustomerReviews->AverageRating,
                        'raters' => $amazon->Items->Item->CustomerReviews->TotalReviews
                    );
                }
                // All we need is the tag
                $tags[] = $book->tag;
                // Add the combined tag string to the meta array
                $meta['tags'] = implode(', ', $tags);
                // Add the meta array
                $records[] = $meta;
            }
            $i++;
        }

        echo '<code><pre>';
        print_r($records);
        echo '</pre></code>';

        if ($sort == 'rating-desc') usort($records, array('browse_model', 'cmp'));

        echo '<code><pre>';
        print_r($records);
        echo '</pre></code>';
        return $records;
    }

    private function cmp($a, $b) {
        if ($a['rating'] == $b['rating']) 
            return strcasecmp($b['title'], $a['title']);
        return $b['rating'] - $a['rating'];
    }


}
```

Comment: You should consider moving the sorting to the database via an `ORDER BY` clause

Comment: The ratings aren't stored in the database - they're created on the fly by Amazon's API.

Comment: `I have a series of rows from a database` hmmm

Comment: This is not a super great question title -- its vague description refers to too many questions on this topic and is therefore likely to have poor searchability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could alternatively use [array_multisort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php)

**deleted code**

Creates a couple extra arrays, but gets the job done; if you put the code into a function or a method as you're doing (pass $records by reference) those will get destroyed on function exit.

Edit: I see you've put into your question that you've tried this. How doesn't it work?

Edit: This works for me:

```
foreach ($records as $rec) {
    $rating[] = $rec['rating'];
    $title[] = strtolower($rec['title']);
}

array_multisort($title, SORT_DESC, $rating, SORT_ASC, $records);

print_r($records);
```

**Another edit:**

Given this array:

```
$records = array(
  0 => 
  array (
    'isbn' => '1847199488',
    'title' => 'CodeIgniter 1.7',
    'rating' => 3.5,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'isbn' => '1847199488',
    'title' => 'CodeIgniter 1.7',
    'rating' => 3,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'isbn' => '1847199488',
    'title' => 'CodeIgniter 1.7',
    'rating' => 3.2,
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'isbn' => '1847199488',
    'title' => 'CodeIgniter 1.7',
    'rating' => 4.5,
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'isbn' => '059615593X',
    'title' => 'CSS Cookbook, 3rd Edition (Animal Guide)',
    'rating' => 3.5,
  ),
  5 => 
  array (
    'isbn' => '0321637984',
    'title' => 'Essential Facebook Development: Build Successful Applications for the Facebook Platform',
    'rating' => 3.5,
  ),
  6 => 
  array (
    'isbn' => '0980576857',
    'title' => 'jQuery: Novice to Ninja',
    'rating' => 4.5,
  ),
  7 => 
  array (
    'isbn' => '0596157134',
    'title' => 'Learning PHP, MySQL, and JavaScript: A Step-By-Step Guide to Creating Dynamic Websites (Animal Guide)',
    'rating' => 4.5,
  ),
);
```

This code:

```
foreach ($records as $rec) {
    $rating[] = $rec['rating'];
    $title[] = strtolower($rec['title']);
}

array_multisort($rating, SORT_DESC, SORT_NUMERIC, $title, SORT_ASC, SORT_STRING, $records);

var_export($records);
```

Will produce this:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'isbn' => '1847199488',
    'title' => 'CodeIgniter 1.7',
    'rating' => 4.5,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'isbn' => '0980576857',
    'title' => 'jQuery: Novice to Ninja',
    'rating' => 4.5,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'isbn' => '0596157134',
    'title' => 'Learning PHP, MySQL, and JavaScript: A Step-By-Step Guide to Creating Dynamic Websites (Animal Guide)',
    'rating' => 4.5,
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'isbn' => '1847199488',
    'title' => 'CodeIgniter 1.7',
    'rating' => 3.5,
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'isbn' => '059615593X',
    'title' => 'CSS Cookbook, 3rd Edition (Animal Guide)',
    'rating' => 3.5,
  ),
  5 => 
  array (
    'isbn' => '0321637984',
    'title' => 'Essential Facebook Development: Build Successful Applications for the Facebook Platform',
    'rating' => 3.5,
  ),
  6 => 
  array (
    'isbn' => '1847199488',
    'title' => 'CodeIgniter 1.7',
    'rating' => 3.2,
  ),
  7 => 
  array (
    'isbn' => '1847199488',
    'title' => 'CodeIgniter 1.7',
    'rating' => 3,
  ),
)
```

Comment: I have nearly this exact snippet of code in my post above. Didn't work (I get the same issue - sorted by rating but desc by title. I can change the sort method to DESC and it doesn't change.

Comment: "But that result isn't correct either. It shows the same result as the usort I tried above."

Comment: @Marcus - See my edited code. After applying some logic it seems to do just what you want.

Comment: @Marcus - And it does work, at least with the array in your question, downvote notwithstanding. Note the addition of strtolower(). (And I am, like everyone else here, just trying to help.)

Comment: Not trying to offend - I downvoted because you recommended an option I'd already listed as tested and failed.

Comment: I just copied and ran that code and I'm still getting the results sorted by rating correctly but the title comes out desc. If I change the title sort option to SORT_ASC, I get the titles in the right order but the ratings start ordering lowest to highest.

Comment: @Marcus - Well, now I see where you're going wrong. The primary sort is done first, then the secondary sort will sort only those items that have identical primary fields. You can't have it sorted completely by both fields; the rating field is sorted only on those elements that have identical titles. Try adding some elements that have identical titles but differing ratings. (It's only an accident of your posted array values that sort by title also seems to sort by rating.)

Comment: Hmm. Interesting. So is there a way to sort by rating and then by title?

Comment: @Marcus - Yes. The first subarray given is the primary sort, the second is the seconday sort (and so on). So to sort by rating first: array_multisort($rating, SORT_ASC, $title, SORT_DESC, $records); (Adjust constants as needed.)

Comment: Ok. So that last comment is exactly what I had before. BUT -- I see you've edited your code to include SORT_NUMERIC and SORT_STRING, which seems to have fixed me right up. I'm not sure why your array has the same books listed multiple times with different ratings (that would never happen), but changing that line in my code finally did what I needed, so thanks.

Comment: @Marcus - You're welcome. I added duplicate titles with differing ratings only to show how a two-element sort actually works, and why previous sorts only _appeared_ to not work. I assumed that it wouldn't happen in actuality; it was just the easiest way to demonstrate.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks again. I appreciate your patience.

Answer (score 5):

Your array is sorted, both by rating and by title.  The problem is that you're sorting case-sensitively, and 'a' comes after 'Z'.

Try using `strcasecmp` instead of `strcmp` when comparing titles.

Also, if the rating will always be a number, you should probably be comparing ratings numerically rather than stringwise.  Use `$b['rating'] - $a['rating']` instead of `strcmp`.

EDIT:

I took the same function you had originally, and the same data, and whipped up a test script.  With the function in a class and marked `private`, PHP warned that the callback to `usort` was invalid, but continued to run (not touching the array).  With the function marked `public`, though, it works as expected.  This leads me to believe that either PHP hates your callback being to a private function, or the class name is wrong.

If you want to be able to use a private function, the call to `usort` apparently needs to be in a function in the same class.  Otherwise `usort` complains about the callback being invalid and refuses to run.

```
class Stuff
{
    public function sort(&$arr)
    {
        usort($arr, array('Stuff', 'cmp'));
    }

    private function cmp($a, $b)
    {
        $ratingCmp = $b['rating'] - $a['rating'];
        if ($ratingCmp == 0) {
            return strcasecmp($a['title'], $b['title']);
        } else {
            return $ratingCmp;
        }
    }
}

Stuff::sort($records);
print_r($records);
```

For me, this prints out the books sorted descending by rating, then ascending by title.  If this doesn't work for you, something's funky.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm getting them in alpha order now. That said, no matter what I do, now the 3.5 ratings come up first. I've tried it about 10 different ways and no matter what I always get the 3.5 ratings first. Any idea why?

Comment: Try switching the order of $a and $b in your rating comparison.  It should work as is, but eh.

Comment: If you can't get it, append the current `cmp` function to your question, so we can see what you're working with now.

Comment: Realized to that it's not actually sorting by ratings - just so happens that the first three items in alpha order by title are the 3 that have a 3.5 rating. So now that I've changed it, it doesn't sort at all.

Comment: Odd, that.  I created a script with what appears to be the same data, and the exact same 'cmp' function you had at the beginning (except it's not in a class).  It sorts fine with just the `strcmp`s replaced.  But then, it also sorts fine with a couple of the variations you had at the end.

Comment: Yeah, I had a lot of trouble with that error earlier until I referenced my model along with the cmd function, like so - usort($records, array('browse_model', 'cmp')); - but that's no longer the case. If I flip the return statement that subtracts the rating of $b from that of $a, it changes the result (shows bottom-rated first) so I know it's able to access the function.

Comment: The bottom-rated items are the 3.5's, which also happen to be the first ones in the list.  This was the same case in which you said a bit ago that the function wasn't sorting at all.

Comment: That's true, but I think this time it's the other way. The point here is when I change the cmp function, my results change, too, and I don't get an error about not being able to find the expected function call in the usort function. Before when I was just putting 'cmp' in the second usort parameter rather than the array, I was getting the same error you mentioned. I tested changing it to public for the benefit of the doubt before my last comment and saw no change - either way it gave the same results.

Comment: (Hope I don't seem argumentative - certainly don't intend to be. I appreciate the advice. Just trying to fit what I'm seeing in a short space).

Comment: I'm just trying to understand why you're getting different results than i am.  :)  Seems with the `usort` call within a function in the class, it works.  Outside the class, not so much.  I'm posting my (working) code as an update.  Let me know how it's different from yours, cause if you can copy/paste that code and it fails, i dunno what else to tell you.

Comment: I added the entire model to the question at the bottom.

Answer (score 2):

Use simple boolean comparison operators for comparing numeric fields such as rating, rather than `strcmp`:

```
private function cmp($a, $b) {
    if ($b['rating'] == $a['rating'])
       return strcmp($b['title'], $a['title']);
    return $b['rating'] - $a['rating'];
}
```

It also looks like you're sorting descending by both rating and title; change your `strcmp` to `return strcmp($a['title'], $b['title'])` to sort by rating(descending) and title(ascending).